# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file: comparison between files not lists

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
import os
import csv


os.chdir("/Users/ady/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/")

with open("/Users/ady/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/file1.txt") as f1:
    contents1 = f1.read()
    print(contents1)

with open("/Users/ady/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/file2.txt") as f2:
    contents2 = f2.read()
    print(contents2)



if f1 == f2:
    print ("The lists l1 and l3 are the same") 
else:
    print ("The lists l1 and l3 are not the same")

temp3 = [] 
for element in f1:
    if element not in f2:
        temp3.append(element)
```

Why does an error occur?

Comment: Ignoring all the problems with indentation, You are using `with` context manager, which automatically close the file(s) for you. Probably you want to compare contents1 and contents2. And the last 3 lines don't make much sense anyway (there multiple problems)

Comment: I mean what does not make sense exactly ? if I do the exact same execute but with lists instead of files it works fine. Do you have an actual comment rather than it does not make sense ?

Comment: You should use `contents1` and `contents2`, not `f1` and `f2`. You just read the file contents into those variables, thus use those variables.

Comment: "but with lists instead of files it works fine": because a file is not a list.

Comment: "Do you have an actual comment rather than it does not make sense": a comment is just a comment, not necessarily a solution, and your reply comes across as a bit aggressive. But read the second sentence of the comment you're replying to, and you'll see a useful suggestion there as well (the same suggestions as mine in fact).

Comment: Given that the code snippet was not properly formatted it was hard to see what your actual intentions are.

Comment: That is not surprising, given that none of your questions is properly formatted or in line with [ask] a good question.

Comment: I think what is meant is, get rid of f1, f2, use contents1,2 directly, Since you are already opening a file with csv , also the last lines are using files before they are read as you  are reading to contents rather then f1,f2

Comment: It's like, having a box of stuff, and instead of comparing the stuff inside the box, you are trying to compare the box as is, and not what is inside of it. I think the last posts mean well. this isn't a code review site, the goal should always be to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare the files `f1` and `f2`, instead of their contents.
However, at time of comparison, these files are no longer open, since you use a `with` context manager, which automatically closes the file after the indented block finished executing.

So there are two problems. If you truly want to compare the *files* themselves (which will return False even if the have identical content, since their names are different), you could do something like this:

```
with open("/Users/ady/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/file1.txt") as f1,
     open("/Users/ady/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/file2.txt") as f2:

    contents1 = f1.read()
    print(contents1)

    contents2 = f2.read()
    print(contents2)


    if f1 == f2:
        print ("The files f1 and f2 are the same") 
    else:
        print ("The files f1 and f2 are not the same")
```

Note that the check is now contained in the `with` context manager, so `f1` and `f2` are open during this check. As stated previously, this `if` block will never run, since the file paths are different, and it will always tell you that the files are not the same.

So what you likely want instead is this:

```
with open("/Users/ady/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/file1.txt") as f1:
    contents1 = f1.read()
    print(contents1)

with open("/Users/ady/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/file2.txt") as f2:
    contents2 = f2.read()
    print(contents2)



if contents1 == contents2:
    print ("The lists l1 and l3 are the same") 
else:
    print ("The lists l1 and l3 are not the same")
```

This way, you are comparing content of the files, not the files themselves.

Comment: thanks a lot Spectre that helps very much! I understand now!